# Submit data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

It is 3rd day I am unable to send data to MySQL.
here are the resources
**db name: school
table name: staff**
**connection.php contains**

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'school') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
?>
```

**and**
**add-teacher.php contains**

```
<form method="post" action="add-teacher.php" >
    <input type="text" name="firstname"  />
    <input type="text" name="lastname"   />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `staff` (`fname`, `lname`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')";

    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        die("DAMMIT");
    } else {
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

I could not fins any error despite no row found at phpmyadmin.
add-teacher.php:
[image: add-teacher.php]

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: post the error with the description you are getting while submitting the data. check with the connection you are creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are establish connection using mysqli and use mysql in run query. As mysql is totally removed in current version.

Use

```
if(!mysqli_query($db,$query))
```

Instead of

```
if(!mysql_query($query))
```

Comment: sorry no success...

Comment: Can you please post error?

Comment: i removed "i" from mysqli_connect and tried no error found but no success too..

Comment: if(!mysqli_query($dbObj,$query))

Comment: No. no. you should go with mysqli.  can you please echo $query and put outout direct in phpmyadmin and tell me success or not?

Comment: has two parameters ut i have not declared $dbObj anywhere

Comment: here is the error

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Xenon\add-teacher.php on line 43

Comment: but you are passing two parameters then how can this error occur?

Comment: and when i use if(!mysqli_query($dbObj,$query))
       it says Notice: Undefined variable: dbObj in C:\xampp\htdocs\Xenon\add-teacher.php on line 43

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Xenon\add-teacher.php on line 43

Comment: Please not use $dbObj its nothing.  please go with $db and make sure your connection.php file is included in add-teacher.php

Comment: yes it has two parameters but it says undefined variable $dbObj

Comment: but why you usgin $dbObj please use $db.

Comment: you made it... thanks...

Comment: Always happy to help. :)